# Should you have ID on columns within a row? bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is it a good idea to use ID in a bootstrap .col which is in a .row? I read somewhere that you should only have columns under .row . Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

       <div id="style1" class="col-12">
       </div>

       <div id="style2" class="col-12">
       </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

or should I make seperate div tags:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

       <div class="col-12">
            <div id="style1">
            </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-12">
            <div id="style2">
            </div>
       </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish a simple bootstrap website. I have looked up bootstrap templates, where none of them put style in the same tag as .col. Is there a correct way, or does it not matter? From a professional and functional view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter: The reason why you shouldn't you use an ID for a particular element usually is that you would like to use the CSS applied to that ID more than once: In this case you should use a class instead of an ID.

But if you are sure you will use those settings only once (or if you don't use *any* CSS for that ID but only want to be able to address that *one* element via Javascript/jQuery), you can use an ID.